# Accessing Kashoo API through Python and SUDS. Problem with time format in authentication token

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to access this API https://www.kashoo.com/api-docs using SUDS in Python.

The Python code I use is the following:

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> client = Client('https://www.kashoo.com/api/v1?wsdl')
>>> token = client.service.doLogin('username', 'password', 'www.kashoo.com', 'en_US', 3000000)
```

The authToken is created without problems:

```
>>> print token
(authToken){
_authenticationCode = "crxQRveuVaDb6swKCJaQKKPiYaY="
_expiryDate = 2011-07-10 12:49:28.000702
_locale = "en_US"
_myUserId = 531772668
_site = "www.kashoo.com"
```

The problem is when I try to encode the token and make an encoded authentication string

```
>>>encodedtoken = client.service.encodeAuthToken(token)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 0, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
   return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
   result = self.send(soapenv)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
   result = self.failed(binding, e)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\suds\client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
 WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Token authentication code is incorrect'
```

The problem seems to be the time format in token. The envelope received from calling the doLogin function is the following:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>                  
 <ns2:doLoginResponse xmlns:ns2="https://www.kashoo.com/api/">
      <token authenticationCode="0WM1DgdaAFrJ7Yz4Up2UWnbVsZk=" expiryDate="2011-07-11T03:33:24.046-07:00" locale="en_US" myUserId="531772668" site="www.kashoo.com"/>
 </ns2:doLoginResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

If I pass that token in the Kashoo API using a tool like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) , it works without problem. However, when I call the encodeAuthToken function from Python using SUDS, the following SOAP envelope is generated:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www.kashoo.com/api/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:encodeAuthToken>
         <token authenticationCode="0WM1DgdaAFrJ7Yz4Up2UWnbVsZk=" expiryDate="2011-07-11T11:33:24.000046+01:00" locale="en_US" myUserId="531772668" site="www.kashoo.com"/>
      </ns1:encodeAuthToken>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Notice how the timeformat of the expiryDate attribute changed:

```
 <token authenticationCode="0WM1DgdaAFrJ7Yz4Up2UWnbVsZk=" expiryDate="2011-07-11T03:33:24.046-07:00" locale="en_US" myUserId="531772668" site="www.kashoo.com"/>
 <token authenticationCode="0WM1DgdaAFrJ7Yz4Up2UWnbVsZk=" expiryDate="2011-07-11T11:33:24.000046+01:00" locale="en_US" myUserId="531772668" site="www.kashoo.com"/>
```

In the token received, the time is specified using milliseconds, while in the token passed on, the time is specified in microsecond.

PROBLEM SOLVED.

In the SUDS library, I modified the suds.sax.date module on line 218 to replace

```
            return dt.time(hour, minute, second, ms)
```

with

```
            return dt.time(hour, minute, second, 1000 * ms)
```

now when I obtain a token, the time attribute is correctly interpreted and passed on

```
>>> print token1
    (authToken){
        _locale = "en_US"
        _authenticationCode = "JQyior8Qprg3+3wuZo8B5JnN3c8="
        _myUserId = 531772668
        _site = "www.kashoo.com"
        _expiryDate = 2011-07-11 18:36:38.136000
       }
>>> token2 = client.service.encodeAuthToken(token1)
>>> print token2
    6454e3af-b09d-4484-90b3-ea2632ab9fe4
```

I'm new at programming and the solution is far from elegant, but it seems to work.

Thanks to @dobesv for your feedback and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can produce a log of what is going "over the wire" as HTTP requests and responses, it might help diagnose the problem.  You certainly seem to be doing the right thing.

Do any other calls work?  How about service.getMyBusinesses(token) ?

Also you can consider using the REST API instead of SOAP, see if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. Other calls in Python using SUDS with the token generated in Python do not work either. I produced a log and made a call with the token that was generated in the log files in soapUI4.0.0 and it worked. Further investigations revealed the timeformat in the token seems to get altered:
<token .... expiryDate="2011-07-11T08:10:08.387-07:00" ... />
<token .... expiryDate="2011-07-11T16:10:08.000387+01:00" ... />
The first token (the one received) does work. The second token (the one passed on in further calls) does not work. Where these three zero's come from is a mystery. Any idea/help ?

Comment: Perhaps you should report a bug back to the SUDS people I don't think they should be changing the timestamp in that manner.